# Adding an extra day into time/date PHP & ACF equation (for a WordPress site)

Tags: php, wordpress, time, advanced-custom-fields

We're having a bit of difficulty in getting a time/date 'if' statement to work correctly. The site is for a company offering ticketing options on events, and we're trying to display a ticket button, only if the event has passed.

We've been using the code below, but this is hiding the ticket buttons once the day begins:

```
<?php if(strtotime(get_sub_field('date'))>time()): ?>
```

*(button code in here)*

```
<?php endif; ?>
```

So for example, if an event is set to occur on May 10th, as soon as we get to May 10th, the ticket button is then hidden (whereas we need this to hide on May 11th — whatever the next calendar day is after the event has occurred).

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you can go.

Lets assume you have event date in $event_date.

```
    $today_date = date('Y-m-d'); //get today's date
    if(strtotime($event_date)) > strtotime($today_date)){
      //Show your button
    }else{
      // Button will not show
    }
```

Comment: Thanks @Shashank, that seems to work perfectly! Exactly what we were after!

Comment: Glad to know it helps you. Can you please up-vote my answer :)

Comment: Thank you! Have done so but I don't think it's showing at the moment as my 'reputation' score isn't above 15 yet :)

Comment: @Dan Ok, now its 17 :)

Answer (score 0):

This code snippet will work for you.

```
<?php 
$today_date = date('Y-m-d'); // current date
$next_day = date('d-m-Y', strtotime("+1 day", $today_date)); 

 if(strtotime(get_sub_field('date'))> strtotime($next_day)){ ?>
    Show your button
<?php }else{ ?>
    Hide Your Button or remove button
<?php }  ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help @Ankit! The other answer seemed to work, but this one looks fairly similar to that so I'm sure this would do the job as well :)